# Open a new terminal tab from the current terminal using command

Tags: terminal

A new terminal window can be opened by a command

```
open -na Terminal
```

Is there a way to open a new terminal *tab*?

Comment: My fav. translation service says that this is a terminal tag (or solder tag): [Solder tag](https://media.rs-online.com/t_large/F1867832-01.jpg). You probably meant a *tab*?

Comment: did you try Cmd+T either this is default behaviour or i make it work like this probably over the Keyboard Menu in Settings App

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to do this through AppleScript, but it can be executed from the command line via `osascript`

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to activate' -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down'
```

Credit:  [StackOverflow - Open new Terminal Tab from command line (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171725/open-new-terminal-tab-from-command-line-mac-os-x)

Comment: You could probably create an alias to put in your .bash_profile to run this command whenever you need to.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. The OP asks to open a tab in the current terminal and you have given a solution that only opens a tab in Mac's native Terminal.

Comment: @IanSteffy - the OP’s question, they use Apple’s native Terminal in the command example.  Is there a Terminal app that you’re specifically looking for an answer to?